In "Ritchie's Fabulae Faciles", why is it "per totam insulam" and not "totam per insulam" or "per insulam totam"?

Tris dies per totam insulam matrem quaerebat; tandem quarto die ad templum Dianae pervenit.
http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/ritchie.html

Why is it "per totam insulam", and not "per insulam totam" or "totam per insulam"? Shouldn't the preposition go right before the noun it modifies? Why would it be "summa cum laude" (with greatest fame), but "per totam insulam"?

It is not a rule of Latin that a preposition must go directly before the noun it modifies, so there's no issue with placing a preposition before an adjective and then a noun.
Preposition + Noun + Adjective, Preposition + Adjective + Noun, and Adjective + Preposition + Noun are all grammatical.
You can even, mainly in poetry, find Noun + Preposition + Adjective.
Aside from adjectives, a genitive noun or noun phrase may intervene between a preposition and its complement, as in "per tuae sagittae dulcia vulnera" (Apuleius Metamorphoses 4.31.4).
That's not to say that word order with prepositions is entirely free: in fact, the position of prepositions in Latin is relatively tightly constrained compared to many other kinds of words. Most of the time, a preposition is followed by a word that has a role of some kind in the noun phrase that is the complement of the preposition, even though it doesn't have to be the head noun. It is rare for a preposition to be placed after the entire noun phrase (although there are limited examples of this in some authors, with some prepositions).
It can be argued that it is better to think of the variation between different orders of preposition, adjective and noun in terms of the noun and adjective (rather than the preposition) having the freedom to be placed in different positions: thus, in Adjective + Preposition + Noun, we have an adjective that is "fronted", or placed discontinuously to the left of its associated noun (as we can also have in contexts where there is no preposition).
The Adjective + Preposition + Noun order, as in "summa cum laude," is often viewed as a stylish or elegant construction, and there are a number of more or less idiomatic phrases that display this word order: however, I remember reading somewhere that prepositional phrases of this form are not actually more frequent overall than those of the form Preposition + Adjective + Noun.
